# Detect Window/Door opening closing using sensors

Tags: sensor

How can we accurately detect whether window/door is opened using different sensors?

Window Switches are most common and accurate way.

Questions:
1.Is it common to use air pressure detection to solve such problems? Can it be done accurately? This thread mentioned to use MS5611 sensor. Can it solve the issue? [Volumetric air sensor for burglar alarm](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/90102/90493)
2.Are there any other accurate way (other than air pressure detection and switches) that can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to find out the state of a door/window, or are you trying to detect intruders?

Comment: @WillDean : To find state of door/window

Comment: Stop posting multiple questions on the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there could ever be a definitive list of ways you could detect the state of the door/window, but obvious ones are:

- Proximity switch (like magnetic window switch used in alarms)
- Mechanical switch (like in a refrigerator, or older car)
- Some kind of optical detection: beam-break or retroflective
- Image analysis using a camera

Air pressure is used to detect doors/windows opening/closing suddenly, not to detect the static state of doors/window.

I would suggest that 99.9999% of all doors/windows in the world which have switches on them use one of the first two techniques.

Comment: Can we use passive infrared proximity sensor ( https://www.adafruit.com/products/466 ) that is used in mobile phones as a way to detect whether window is opened or closed? The device (that has sensor) is placed on window glass and when that device detects a window frame it will trigger alarm.

Will it work even if bright sunlight is on the window?

I don't want to use window sensors with magnetic switch.